# How to Pass Scope Variable in ng-click and how to access the Parameter in angularJS Function within Controller

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-click

How to Pass Scope Variable in ng-click and how to access the Parameter in angularJS Function within Controller ?

My Source Code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td><a href="" ng-click="SuperFunction('{{x.Name}}')">{{ x.Country }}</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .then(function (response) { $scope.names = response.data.records; });
    $scope.SuperFunction = function (id) {
        alert(id);
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My Ouptput Screen Shot at the Time of Click
[Output Screen Shot in Firefox with Inspect Element Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9y2Q.jpg)

I got an parameter value as `{{x.Name}}` instead of actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake is here:

```
ng-click="SuperFunction('{{x.Name}}')"
```

It should be:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td><a href="" ng-click="SuperFunction(x.Name)">{{ x.Country }}</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Change as per suggestion. It will work.